# Visual Studio Regex Search Question

Tags: regex, visual-studio

How do I search for lines in a file which contain "A" but not "B" with Regex search?

Thanks.

Comment: I hope you really mean single letters. If `A` or `B` stand for some longer text, you're out of luck because VS's regex engine doesn't support lookahead.

Answer (score 1):

```
^[^B]*A[^B]*$
```

Ignore this: padding to reach 30 chars.